# How to rotate a picture using jogl?

Tags: jogl

Dear Friends,Can anyone tell me how to show one picture in GLCanvas and by using mouse how to rotate a picture in the GLCanvas.I m new to this jogl developement.Can u pls provide me how to do this.If possible provide me some code snippet and some reference site to get a clear idea about jogl developement.

regards,
s.kumaran.

Answer (score 2):

To show an image on GLCanvas , create a polygon using **gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POLYGON)** and load the texture using the **Class TextureIO** .Then using the MouseListener in Java Swings ,you can easily control the rotation of the image(i.e,the textured polygon) by simply changing the position of Camera or doing some transformations( **"gl.glRotate(angle,x-axis,y-axis,z-axis)** in your case") in Model-View matrix .

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this will be to texture a Quad with the picture and then apply affine transforms to that Quad. Rendering this quad will let you see a rotating picture you can do pretty much any transform by shifting the vertices of the Quad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are drawing a 3D scene and want to change it's orientation, rather than having a 2D image which you wish to rotate.

The short answer is that it takes place in two parts. You need to store an orientation of your scene as a 4x4 matrix (homogeneous matrix - search for it if you don't know what that is). You first need to write code that translates a mouse drag into a change of that 4x4 matrix. So when the mouse is dragged up apply an appropriate rotation or whatever to the matrix.

Then you need to redraw the scene, but using the new transformed 4x4 matrix. Use glMatrixMode to specify which matrix (use either GL_PROJECTION or GL_MODELVIEW) and then functions like glMultMatrixf() to manipulate the appropriate matrix.

If that didn't make sense pick up an OpenGL tutorial on how to rotate scenes. OpenGL and JOGL are close enough that methods from OpenGL work in JOGL.